# Why is the following string comparison code returning TRUE after appending 0x81

Tags: c#, .net, string, encoding, string-comparison

The following code is a workaround that will allow us to use some functionality from our existing product without changing any code in it. It is a good thing for us but I want to understand why this works? What is special about the 0x81 character?

```
"A".Equals(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0x41, 0x81 }), StringComparison.InvariantCulture) // Returns TRUE
```

The above code works for CurrentCulture and InvariantCulture but NOT for Ordinal. That makes sense because in ordinal, each byte is compared which would fail in the code above. And it does not work with Default Encoding (SBCS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The byte sequence { 0x41, 0x81 } is not valid UTF-8, as the byte 0x41 represents the 'A' character by itself, and the byte 0x81 cannot occur at the beginning of a UTF-8 encoding sequence, and is an error in this position.

Since Encoding.UTF8.GetString() is not throwing an exception, it is probably adding a replacement character (U+FFFD) to the string, as described in [choosing a fallback strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx) on MSDN.

So you may be comparing the string "A" with the string "A"+replacement character, and some string comparisons may ignore replacement characters, and thus return true.

Comment: Okay. Is this a bug "ignoring replacement chars" that could be fixed in the coming release? If I take the string and call UTF8.GetBytes(...) on it then I get these four bytes: 65, 239, 191, 189.

Comment: Right, 65 is 0x41, so that's the "A". The remaining three bytes are the UTF-8 encoding of U+FFFD, the replacement character that is added to the string in response to seeing the original invalid 0x81 byte in the input. This isn't a bug in Encoding.UTF8, it's an entirely reasonable thing for it to do. You can configure it to behave differently as described on MSDN, but you might need to figure out what you are trying to do, first :)

Comment: @A9S6 If you are expecting UTF-8, you should fail already at the point where you got `0x81` and demand valid UTF-8 from the source. Public web servers can receive arbitrary bytes from arbitrary clients and shouldn't attempt to deal with it as legit browser clients always send valid UTF-8. But misconfigured alternative clients or malicious requests can send invalid UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

You just remove the culture information then it will work fine,
i.e use "A".Equals(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0x41, 0x81 })) 
in place of
"A".Equals(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0x41, 0x81 }), StringComparison.InvariantCulture)